# Mongoose Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I cannot get a result with aggregation option parameter. Here is my aggregation:-

```
var emails = getAllEmails();
var listMatchColl = 'list_matches_' + insertedId;
SurveyDL.aggregate([
     { $match: { email: { $in: emails } } },
     { $out: listMatchColl }
 ], {
   allowDiskUse: true
 }).exec(function(err, data) {
  if (err) return console.log('err', err);
    console.log('data',data);
 });
}
```

When i execute above code it thrown and error i.e,

> Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators
>       at Aggregate.append (/home/vivek/nrich/node_modules/mongoose/lib/aggregate.js:89:11)
>       at new Aggregate (/home/vivek/nrich/node_modules/mongoose/lib/aggregate.js:48:17)

I have also use the alternative way but it still throw same error. Alternative way :-

```
var emails = getAllEmails();
var listMatchColl = 'list_matches_' + insertedId;
SurveyDL.aggregate([
     { $match: { email: { $in: emails } } },
     { $out: listMatchColl }
 ], {
   allowDiskUse: true
 },function(err, data) {
  if (err) return console.log('err', err);
    console.log('data',data);
 });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try setting the **[`allowDiskUse()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-allowDiskUse)** option for the aggregation query:

```
var emails = getAllEmails();
var listMatchColl = 'list_matches_' + insertedId;
SurveyDL.aggregate([
    { '$match': { 'email': { '$in': emails } } },
    { '$out': listMatchColl }
 ]).allowDiskUse(true)
   .exec(function(err, data) {
        if (err) return console.log('err', err);
        console.log('data',data);
    });
```

or using the fluent API:

```
SurveyDL.aggregate()
        .match({ 'email': { '$in': emails } })
        .append({ '$out': listMatchColl })
        .allowDiskUse(true)
        .exec(function(err, data) {
            if (err) return console.log('err', err);
            console.log('data',data);
        });
```

---

You might be running over the 16MB aggregation size [limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/) and the **[`allowDiskUse()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-allowDiskUse)** option is not sufficient if your data will be > 16MB since it just lets you use sort when your data is large. Consider using the aggregation **[`cursor`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-cursor)** form to access your aggregated documents:

```
var cursor = SurveyDL.aggregate([
    { $match: { email: { $in: emails } } }    
 ]).cursor({ batchSize: 1000 }).exec();

cursor.each(function(error, doc) {
  // use doc
});
```

---

Comment: thanks for reply @chridam, but still i stuck in problem. Now it throw error `MongoError: attempt to write outside buffer bounds`. My mongodb version is 3.2.6 and mongoose is 4.1.2 and i am using `bluebird`

Comment: @vineetsahCL Added another option.

Comment: by using `cursor` i got error i.e, `RangeError: attempt to write outside buffer bounds`

Comment: Actually i upload a csv file approx 20mb with approx 900000 emails.

Answer (score 0):

var **emails** must be **Array**.

listMatchColl must be **String**.

```
{ $out: 'listMatchColl' }
```

and if you use **$out**, you can`t see result your aggregation.
Your result in new collection 'listMatchColl'.

Comment: actually, `listMatchColl` dynamic created. I have updated question please check.

Comment: But it throw an error `Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators at Aggregate` and unable to create collections.

Comment: like `emails=['abc@gmail.com','xyz@gmail.com',.....]'`, one more things that there is approx 900000 value in my `emails` variable. I think that i have missing somethings here.

Comment: sorry, i can`t repeat same error. Try aggregate with small array, because i run same aggregation and get result.

Comment: /node_modules/mongoose/lib/aggregate.js:574
console.log(k), you must have only [ '$match' ]
[ '$out' ]. If you have another values, i think you need edit your query